# Behaviour of intrinsic exp function in fortran with iso_c_binding

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

In order to check some properties of the iso_c_binding in fortran, I wrote a little program

```
program double
    use iso_c_binding, only : C_DOUBLE, C_INT32_T, C_FLOAT
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: rk  = C_DOUBLE
    integer, parameter :: rk4 = C_FLOAT
    integer, parameter :: ik  = C_INT32_T
    integer(kind=ik) :: i, j
    integer(kind=ik), parameter :: n = 10
    real(kind=rk), dimension (n) :: array, narray, oarray
    real(kind=rk) :: barray(n) = (/(i, i=1,n,1)/)

    do i = 1, n
      oarray(i) = 1.d0 * real(i)
      array(i) = exp(real(i))
    end do
    narray(:) = exp(oarray(:))
    barray(:) = exp(barray(:))
    do i = 1, n
      write(*,*), array(i), narray(i), barray(i)
    end do

  end program double
```

Compiling with gfortran (gfortran -o prog -Wall -I. -lm build/prog.o)
and running gives the following result:

```
2.7182817459106445  2.7182818284590451  2.7182818284590451    
7.3890562057495117  7.3890560989306504  7.3890560989306504     
20.085536956787109  20.085536923187668  20.085536923187668     
54.598148345947266  54.598150033144236  54.598150033144236     
148.41316223144531  148.41315910257660  148.41315910257660     
403.42880249023438  403.42879349273511  403.42879349273511     
1096.6331787109375  1096.6331584284585  1096.6331584284585     
2980.9580078125000  2980.9579870417283  2980.9579870417283     
8103.0839843750000  8103.0839275753842  8103.0839275753842     
22026.464843750000  22026.465794806718  22026.465794806718
```

It seems that even the value 'array(1)' has some error in it as it already deviates from e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Where does this behaviour come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your calculation for `array`,

```
array(i) = exp(real(i))
```

is done in single precision. The array itself is double precision, but the expression `real(i)` is single precision because the default real type is single precision, and hence, you can only expect 7 digits of accuracy from `exp` when called on it. The other arrays are computed in full double precision.

Try replacing `exp(real(i))` with `exp(real(i,rk))`, and the discrepancy should go away.

Comment: You should be able to do `array(i) = exp(real(i, kind=rk))`